# Flask user input to run a python script

Tags: python, file, flask, input, request

I was trying to build an URL from an user input. 
So the url would always be the same :

```
www.example.com/
```

and the input from user will build the url into something like :

```
www.example.com/USERINPUT-1.jpg
```

I needed to build them like this : from the index.html into /generate root. 
I wasn't able to figure it out...I was moving chairs here and there with no luck

**Here's my run.py**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET'])
def generate():
    prefix = request.args.get('prefix')
    urls = []
    for number in range(1, 7):
        urls.append('https://example.com/{p}-{n}.jpg'.format(p=prefix, n=number))
    return jsonify(result=urls)
```

**Here's my index.html :**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
   <title>Image Grabber v1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#download').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/generate', {
        prefix: $('input[name="prefix"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script><br>
 <h2>Image Grabber v1.0</h2>
<p><input type=text size=45 name=prefix>
   <span id=result></span>
<p><button type="submit" id=download>Download</button></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

@Jatimir helped me to solve my problem...and I was able to get it to work. Question solved.

Comment: You understand that a web application can only access the server's filesystem, not the client's one ? (unless the server and client are running on the same computer of course).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - emmmm, not really, what do u mean ?

Comment: I mean that unless every of your users runs the whole flask app (server proces) on their own computers, there's no way your flask app can write the downloaded files on their computers - the server can only access it's own filesystem.

Comment: Unless of course you then show a page with download links for the files your app retrieved and let the user download them manually, or something similar (you can zip the files in a single archive for example), but this will still requires TWO downloads: the flask app downloading files from tennis-warehouse and storing them on the server's filesystem, then the user downloading the files from the flask app.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ohhh wow...I kinda imagined that being a simple thing...turns out...it's not...hmmmm...so it's more a Flask thing or a python thing than ? How I share my script with my colleagues...without installing python and so on on every pc ? ~confused now...

Comment: It has absolutely nothing to do with flask nor python, you'd have the very same issue with just any language / framework. And the reason why it's not possible are quite obvious - you wouldn't want to allow any arbitrary web server on the net to access your own computer's filesystem, would you ? (security is a huge and complex problem already without such a "feature").

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers what if me as the user, want to download the files though ? where's the issue ? Since when download files that you want became a security issue ?  Just making sure we're in the same boat...I'm trying to get to download files that I WANT using a python script nicely embeded into a Flask web app.

Comment: I don't mean you cannot download file from a server (you send a request to the url serving the file, the server returns a response with the file's content as body), just that the server cannot write to the client's filesystem. Your script is writing files to the local filesystem (cf the `#update the path to your local desktop` comment), and _this_ is not going to work here.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers "you send a request to the url serving the file, the server returns a response with the file's content as body" - there u go, we talk same language now ! the part of writing to local filesystem will figure out later. Like I said, I just did the simple hello world part. From there I have no Idea how to embed my python into Flask. Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I updated my question, if you can have a look please

Comment: I don't think your edit makes the question any clearer, quite on the contrary.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ohhh...I thought it's gonna be easier to run it and check the problem...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Have a look now....maybe make more sense to you

Comment: " Now I'm stuck into downloading multiple files at once. With one click. No zip please." => can you PLEASE stop editing the same post over and over again to ask a new question each time ??? __stackoverlow is not a helpdesk or a forum__, it's a technical knowledge base (in a Q/A form). What you're doing here is just ruining the whole concept.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the post has been edited many times, each time asking a new question, and as such has become totally useless as part or a knowldege base.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sure...how do I mark this question solved than ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem, here is the solution : Build an url from an user input. Sorry for making it so confusing !

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/generate', methods=['GET'])
def generate():
    prefix = request.args.get('prefix')
    urls = []
    for number in range(1, 7):
        urls.append('https://example.com/{p}-{n}.jpg'.format(p=prefix, n=number))
    return jsonify(result=urls)
```

Html file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
   <title>Image Grabber v1.0</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<script type=text/javascript>
  $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#download').bind('click', function() {
      $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/generate', {
        prefix: $('input[name="prefix"]').val()
      }, function(data) {
        $("#result").text(data.result);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
</script><br>
 <h2>Image Grabber v1.0</h2>
<p><input type=text size=45 name=prefix>
   <span id=result></span>
<p><button type="submit" id=download>Download</button></p>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```